# Parse Cloud code query.withinKilometers

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

(Edit 1)

I'm trying to work with the cloud code and GeoPoint.  With the function "query.withinKilometers" I have a pointer to the Location Class but when I try to call the function I get the error "invalid key name".  What is the right way to do this?  I could not find anything in the documentation, here is a file of the cloud function.

Error: "code":105,"message":"Invalid key name: [object Object]"

here de documentation: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.html

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getCloseFindings", function(request, response){
var query           = new Parse.Query("findings");
var locQuery        = query.include("location");
var LocQuery        = locQuery.get("geoLocation");
var Loc_Lat         = request.params.Latitude;
var Loc_Long        = request.params.Longitude;
var UserLocation    = new Parse.GeoPoint(Loc_Lat,Loc_Long);
var RadiusLocation  = request.params.Radius;

query.equalTo("isDeleted", false);
query.withinKilometers(locQuery, UserLocation, 100);
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        if(results === undefined){
            var response_jsonArr = {
                code : 404,
                message : "Not Found"
            };
            response.success(response_jsonArr);
        }else{
            var jsonArr = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i ) {
                var finding_location    = results[i].get("location");
                jsonArr.push({
                    name: results
                });
            }
            response.success(jsonArr);
        }
    }, error: function(error){
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an object to [query.withinKilometers](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.Query.html#withinKilometers) as the first parameter when you should be passing a String.  Try using the key from your query.include call instead, like this:

```
query.withinKilometers("location", userLocation, 100);
```

Comment: or maybe "geoLocation"?

Comment: i tried those variation: 
query.include("location.geoLocation") 
query.withinKilometers("location",UserLocation, Distance)

Comment: did you try "geoLocation"?

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know what the differences between a String and an Object are, or what a key is, I'd suggest you do some research and maybe work on something easier.

Comment: Yes i did, i asked to the support team, if i get a solution o better way to do it will post